# How do you change a recipient's email address with the SendGrid v3 API?

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to use the Sendgrid v3 API to change the email address of an existing Recipient.

Using this example: [Update Recipient [PATCH]](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Update-Recipient-PATCH), I am able to update everything but the email address.  But if I put in a new email address, it is inserted as a new one with the old one remaining with the original recipient.

Is this supported by the API and if so, how is it done?